# Cordova log file is not created

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

Following the instructions here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

After running:

```
cordova emulate ios
```

The last line output in the console is:

```
logPath: <path from root>/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

But, that file does not exist.

In:

```
hello/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/config.xml
```

These lines are present:

```
<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

I tried running via XCode and the log messages do appear in its console.

What am I missing here?